# ActionScript 2.0 dynamic smoothing

Tags: flash, image, actionscript, bitmapdata

I'm trying to make smoothing for images which loaded with `loadclip()`.
I found function for smoothing and it works but only for movieclips located in `_level0`, for example `_level0.mc`, but I want to smooth children MC, for example `_level0.parent_mc.children_mc` and then image just dissapears. 
smoothing function:

```
here = this; // trace(here) == _level0
bg_smooth = function (bg):Void {
    var bg_depth:Number = bg.getDepth();
    var bg_name:String = bg._name; 
    var bg_parent = bg._parent;
    var bg_bitmap_temp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(bg._width, bg._height, true, 0x00FFFFFF);
    bg_bitmap_temp.draw(bg);
    removeMovieClip(bg);
    bg_parent.createEmptyMovieClip(bg_name,bg_depth);
    here[bg_name].bitmapObj = bg_bitmap_temp.clone();
    bg_bitmap_temp.dispose();
    here[bg_name].attachBitmap(here[bg_name].bitmapObj,1,"auto",true);
};
```

other code:

```
var loader:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
var mclL:Object = new Object(); 
mclL.onLoadProgress = function(target, loadedBytes, totalBytes) { 
 //trace(Math.round((loadedBytes / totalBytes) * 100) + "%"); 
}; 
loader.addListener(mclL);    
mclL.onLoadInit = function(element) { 
    bg_smooth(element); // trace(element) == _level0.mc or _level0.parent_mc.children_mc
};

loader.loadClip("img/image.jpg", mc); // <= works
//loader.loadClip("img/image.jpg", parent_mc.children_mc); // <= not works
```

also tried to write `_level0.parent_mc['children_mc']` instead of `parent_mc.children_mc` and to make `here == _level0.parent_mc` - still no luck. If I remove `bg_smooth(element)` on load complete then all works fine but of course smoothing disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another working function. May be helpful for someone else.

```
function applySmoothing(target:MovieClip) {
    var mcParent:MovieClip = target._parent;
    var mcName:String = target._name;
    var myBitmap:BitmapData = new BitmapData(target._width, target._height);
    myBitmap.draw(target);
    target.removeMovieClip();
    target.attachBitmap(myBitmap, 1, "auto", true);
}
```